Aws-amplify is not working with multiple providers
I already integrated Google provider on AWS Cognito which is working well.

I'm integrating one more provider like Amazon Or Facebook provider. the configuration for authentication has been finished. But when redirecting to my app, aws-amplify can not post to https://cognito-identity.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/

App.js file (react)
  componentDidMount() {
    const identityProvider = getDataStorage("identity_provider")
    switch (identityProvider) {
      case "amazonClient":
        Amplify.configure(amazonClient)
        break;
      case "facebookClient":
        Amplify.configure(facebookClient)
        break;
      default:
        Amplify.configure(googleClient)
        break;
    }
  }

aws-export.js file
const googleClient = {
    region: process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_COGNITO_REGION,
    userPoolId: process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID,
    userPoolWebClientId: process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_COGNITO_GOOGLE_APP_CLIENT_ID,
    identityPoolId: process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_COGNITO_IDENTITY_POOL_ID,
    oauth: {
      domain: 'abc-xyz.com',
      responseType: "code",
      redirectSignIn: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_REDIRECT_URL + "callback",
      redirectSignOut: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_REDIRECT_URL
    },
};

const amazonClient = {
  Auth: {
    identityPoolId: process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_COGNITO_IDENTITY_POOL_ID,
    region: process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_COGNITO_REGION,
    userPoolId: process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID,
    userPoolWebClientId: process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_COGNITO_AMAZON_APP_CLIENT_ID,
    oauth: {
      domain: 'abc-xyz.com',
      scope: ['profile'],
      redirectSignIn: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_REDIRECT_URL + "callback",
      redirectSignOut: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_REDIRECT_URL,
      responseType: 'code' // code or token
    }
  },
};

const facebookClient = {
  Auth: {
    identityPoolId: process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_COGNITO_IDENTITY_POOL_ID,
    region: process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_COGNITO_REGION,
    userPoolId: process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID,
    userPoolWebClientId: process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_COGNITO_FACEBOOK_APP_CLIENT_ID,
    oauth: {
      domain: 'abc-xyz.com',
      scope: ['profile'],
      redirectSignIn: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_REDIRECT_URL + "callback",
      redirectSignOut: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_REDIRECT_URL,
      responseType: 'code' // code or token
    }
  },
};
export { googleClient, amazonClient, facebookClient };


Please support me what is missing to Amazon/Facebook provider can be worked.
Thanks
